# How do I customise my TestSuite tests in Junit 4?

Tags: java, junit

In the code below, the `ExampleTest` class contains 5 tests.  However, I want to run only two of them from the `ExampleTestSuite` class using JUNIT.

```
public class ExampleTest extends TestCase {
    private Example example;
    public ExampleTest(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        example= new Example();
    }

    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
        example= null;
    }

    public void test1() {

    }
    public void test2() {

    }
    public void test3() {

    }
    public void test4() {

    }
    public void test5() {

    }

}
```

This is my code below that was done in JUnit 3, but how do I do it in JUnit version 4?

```
public class ExampleTestSuite {

    public static Test suite() {
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite(ExampleTestSuite.class.getName());
        suite.addTest(new ExampleTest("test1"));
        suite.addTest(new ExampleTest("test3"));
        return (Test) suite;
    }
}
```

Comment: Conversion between two versions of JUnit is off-topic. Stackoverflow is not a code conversion service. If you're having difficulties rewriting your code, address a specific problem in your question.

Comment: I'm not asking you to convert all the classes, I already did it using annotations.  I only don't know How to limit the tests in JUnit 4.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Categories` runner introduced in [JUnit 4.8](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/doc/ReleaseNotes4.8.md) like this:

```
/**
 * Marker class to be used with the @Category annotation of JUnit.
 */
public class SmokeTests {}


/**
 * Your original test class converted to JUnit 4.
 */
public class ExampleTest {
    private Example example;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        example = new Example();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        example = null;
    }

    @Test
    @Category(SmokeTests.class)
    public void test1() {}

    @Test
    public void test2() {}

    @Test
    @Category(SmokeTests.class)
    public void test3() {}

    @Test
    public void test4() {}

    @Test
    public void test5() {}
}


/**
 * Your original test suite class converted to JUnit 4.
 */
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@SuiteClasses(ExampleTest.class)
@IncludeCategory(SmokeTests.class)
public class ExampleTestSuite {}
```